# Why does my application audio stop working after turning off and turning on my tv?

Tags: xna

I'm currently developing an application in XNA and using a TV with HDMI for video and audio. When I turn the TV off then on again the application audio ceases to work. However, system sounds do still work. Does anyone have any ideas on why this happens?

I'm using a motherboard with integrated Intel HD graphics to connect the TV and use it as a monitor.

Comment: What do you mean with `motherboard with integrated intel hd graphics`? Is your TV connected to your PC as a monitor? Do other applications have the same issue, perhaps check other XNA applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a similar issue in regards to audio jack sensing in windows: 
https://superuser.com/questions/249878/disable-windows-sound-card-jack-sensing

The same solution solved my problem:

- Go to
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}000\GlobalSettings
- Change the value EnableDynamicDevices to zero.
- Restart your system.

Hopefully this will help others that have issues with this and XNA in the future.